# ¿Como puedo pasar el valor del input type hidden de la opcion seleccionada en un formulario a otra pagina en php?

Tags: php, html, formularios, post

tengo el siguiente problema:

Al pasar las variables s_nombre y s_um a otra web solo entrega la de la ultima opción listada en el formulario, no asi la seleccionada por el usuario en el input type radio. La única variable que entrega bien es la de s_codigo.

Este es el código que envia:

```
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
?>
    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
        <li class="list-group-item" style="padding:.5rem 1.25rem">
            <div>                    
                <input type="radio" name="s_codigo" value="<?php echo $columna['s_codigo'] ?>" /><?php echo $columna['s_nombre'] ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="s_nombre" value="<?php echo $columna['s_nombre'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="s_um" value="<?php echo $columna['s_um'] ?>">
                <span style="float:right;" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"><?php echo $columna['s_um'] ?></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>        
<?php }
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Y este es el que recibe:

```
<?php
$s_codigo = $_POST['s_codigo'];
$s_nombre = $_POST['s_nombre'];
$s_um = $_POST['s_um'];
?>
```

¿Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: ¿Cual es el `name` y el `value` del `input radio`? ¿El `radio` es el último `input` del formulario? ¿Hay algun `javascript` involucrado?

Comment: Cuantos elementos contiene `$resultado`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentaré adivinar que por el hecho de "encerrar" los elementos de la lista en un `<div>` pienses que estos tendrán una conexión entre ellos, y no es así. Al momento en que seleccionas un `radio` no hay nada que le diga a la `página` que los los `input hidden` se relaciona con ese `radio`. La solución puede ser que utilices `JavaScript` para darle ese dinamismo que necesita tu código.

Si no le que necesitas es solo usas PHP, lo que se me ocurre rápido es que realmente no necesitas traer los datos escondidos de esa consulta que realizas, puedes solo llamar el dato del `radio` y pasar ese dato en tu `form`. Cuando estés en la otra `pagina` ahora sí vas y consultas los datos restantes.

Comment: Tenias razón, efectivamente y equivocadamente creía eso. Lo solucioné realizando un query a la base de datos con el s_codigo del input radio que si lograba pasar, con eso obtuve los otros que necesitaba.
¡Muchas gracias!